# Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException' in EntityFramework.dll

Tags: .net, entity-framework, dll, metadata, bin

I am facing this issue in my .Net application, I have recently cloned this application in my system started running the source code
1.First I got the

Compiler Error message: `CS1069: The type name 'HttpClient' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Net.Http'` and found that this dll is not present in the bin folder so copied from my colleague's machine and added that into my project bin folder after this I was able to run my application once,
then next  time onwards couldn't run the application and faced the below exception
2.Exception thrown:

```
'System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException' in EntityFramework.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException' in EntityFramework.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException' in EntityFramework.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException' in EntityFramework.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException' in EntityFramework.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException' in EntityFramework.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException' in EntityFramework.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException' in EntityFramework.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException' in EntityFramework.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException' in EntityFramework.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException' in EntityFramework.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException' in EntityFramework.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException' in EntityFramework.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException' in EntityFramework.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException' in EntityFramework.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException' in EntityFramework.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException' in EntityFramework.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException' in EntityFramework.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException' in EntityFramework.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException' in EntityFramework.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException' in EntityFramework.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException' in EntityFramework.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException' in EntityFramework.dll
The program '[23420] iisexpress.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[23420] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 2147943401 (0x800703e9).
```

Also in the bin folder its shown like this when I keep mouse pointer on the file it says ignored..is this causing any problem?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACOg3.png)